# Bash Environment Variable

Tags: unix

I want to define a permanent environment variable to view the last text file in a folder. I added this line in `.bashrc` file:

```
export DUMMY="less foldername/`ls foldername/ | tail -n 1`"
```

The folder is like this:

```
foldername/
|_ file1
|_ file2
|_ file3
|_ file4
...
```

The problem is, whenever I use `$DUMMY`, it opens always the same file (e.g. `file3`) which is one of the last ones but not very recent one and it is not changing. What is my mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't an `alias` be better for this case?

```sh
alias dummy="less foldername/`ls -tr foldername/ | tail -n 1`"
```

Then you can use:

```sh
dummy
```

[Alias vs export](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129608/alias-vs-export-for-simple-commands)

I add `-tr` options to `ls`:
`-t` - sort by time & date
`-r` - list in reverse order